# Convert MySQL table from one vertical column to multi horizontal columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to convert that table

```
id | main_id       | image
1  | 10            | 52343.jpg   
2  | 10            | 52344.jpg  
3  | 10            | 52345.jpg 
4  | 11            | 52346.jpg   
5  | 11            | 52347.jpg  
6  | 11            | 52348.jpg 
7  | 11            | 52349.jpg   
8  | 12            | 52350.jpg  
9  | 12            | 52351.jpg
```

To be like that:

```
id | main_id  | image1    | image2    | image3    | image4
1  | 10       | 52343.jpg | 52344.jpg | 52345.jpg |
2  | 11       | 52346.jpg | 52347.jpg | 52348.jpg | 52349.jpg 
3  | 12       | 52350.jpg | 52351.jpg |
```

Target table needs to be horizontal with separate column for each record.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data siplay in application level code

Comment: use group_concat. `SELECT main_id, group_concat(image separator '|') FROM docs GROUP BY main_id;` and split image in application.

Comment: I did that in MySQL Workbench but the amount of images are too much and there are a limit for characters that MySQL Workbench cell can accommodate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+ then we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY main_id ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY main_id) id,
    main_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN image END) AS image1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN image END) AS image2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN image END) AS image3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN image END) AS image4
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    main_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just tested it but it shows a syntax error in the first line.

Comment: Then you're not using MySQL 8 or later.  In which case, you might want to handle this in your presentation layer.  My answer is working in the demo.